# Laravel - Lost migrations table content

Tags: laravel-4, migration

I am using Laravel 4.2 and accidentally I lost `migrations` table content. I can't run any migrate because tables already exists.

How can I fill existing tables migrations in `migrations` table?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I fixed this problem:

Firstly I list all migrations files (which are already migrated in database):

```
$files = File::allFiles('app/database/migrations');
    foreach($files as $file)
    {
        $f = explode('/', $file);
        echo replace('.php', '', (string)end($f)) . '<br>';

    }
```

Then I insert them in `migrations` table and I updated `batch` field value:

`update migrations set batch = 1`